# Grouping of elements to new element based on attribute

Tags: xslt

I need to group elements without an attribute into one new element. Depending on if the attribute @single the h2 should either be placed in a new container, or be places grouped with the h2s in sequence without @single. I'm struggling with the group for text 2,3,4. Do I need to create a template for h1 then us an xsl:for-each? Is there  a smarter way to do it?

Source:

```
<h1>
    <h2 single="true" />
    <h2 single="true" />
    <h2>1</h2>
    <h2 single="true" />
    <h2>2</h2>
    <h2>3</h2>
    <h2>4</h2>
    <h2 single="true" />
    <h2>5</h2>
</h1>
```

Result

```
<h1>
    <containertypeA>
        <h2 single="true" />
    </containertypeA>
    <containertypeA>
        <h2 single="true" />
    </containertypeA>
    <containertypeB>
        <h2>1</h2>
    </containertypeB>
    <containertypeA>
        <h2 single="true" />
    </containertypeA>
    <containertypeB>
        <h2>2</h2>
        <h2>3</h2>
        <h2>4</h2>
    </containertypeB>
    <containertypeA>
        <h2 single="true" />
    </containertypeA>
    <containertypeB>
        <h2>5</h2>
    </containertypeB>
</h1>
```

Comment: Which version of XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible XSLT 1.0 solution is following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" 
 indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/> 
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="h2[@single='true']">
    <containertypeA>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </containertypeA>
  </xsl:template> 
  <xsl:template match="h2[not(@single='true') and 
       not(preceding-sibling::h2[1][not(@single='true')])]">
    <containertypeB>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::h2[1][not(@single='true')]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="sibling"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </containertypeB>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="h2" mode="sibling">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="copy"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::h2[1][not(@single='true')]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="sibling"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="h2[not(@single='true') and 
   preceding-sibling::h2[1][not(@single='true')]]" mode="copy">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="h2[not(@single='true') and 
    preceding-sibling::h2[1][not(@single='true')]]"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

when applied to the input XML produces the output

```
<h1>
   <containertypeA>
      <h2 single="true"/>
   </containertypeA>
   <containertypeA>
     <h2 single="true"/>
   </containertypeA>
   <containertypeB>
     <h2>1</h2>
   </containertypeB>
   <containertypeA>
     <h2 single="true"/>
   </containertypeA>
   <containertypeB>
     <h2>2</h2>
     <h2>3</h2>
     <h2>4</h2>
   </containertypeB>
   <containertypeA>
     <h2 single="true"/>
   </containertypeA>
   <containertypeB>
     <h2>5</h2>
   </containertypeB>
</h1>
```

The template

```
<xsl:template match="h2[@single='true']">
```

copies each matching `h2` in a `<containertypeA>`.
The template

```
<xsl:template match="h2[not(@single='true') and 
     not(preceding-sibling::h2[1][not(@single='true')])]">
```

matches all `h2`which have no `@single` attribute with the value `true` and no first preceding sibling `h2` without `@single='true'`. This templates wraps the matching `h2` in a `<containertypeB>` and applies the `template mode="sibling"` for the following first sibling without `@single='true'`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::h2[1][not(@single='true')]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="sibling"/>
```

The `<xsl:template match="h2" mode="sibling">` copies the `h2` using the template with mode="copy":

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="copy"/>
```

and applies itself for all following first siblings without `@single='true'`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::h2[1][not(@single='true')]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="sibling"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Finally, the empty template

```
<xsl:template match="h2[not(@single='true') and 
preceding-sibling::h2[1][not(@single='true')]]"/>
```

matches all `h2` elements that have already been copied into the `<containertypeB>`.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for your help! Highly appreciated! Your comments made it easy to understand I